# Build Django HttpRequest from Raw Request data

Tags: python, django, httprequest, wsgi

I have a log file full of archived raw HTTP Requests (ie a string with the GET request and client HTTP headers).

I have some existing Django Views that I would like to re-use to process the raw requests (so I can take advantage of some of the side-effects already implemented in the views).  My plan is to process these archived requests periodically in a celery task.

The Django `view` needs to be able to access the Headers and Cookies of the request in order to function.  What is the correct way to reconstruct the Django `HTTP Request` object from this raw data?

Sample data:

```
GET /log/?pk=1e455a1038e HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.69 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: fc=fcVal=68335707752227284;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two obvious solutions:

1/ write your own HttpRequest subclass and your own handler (cf `django.http.request` and `django.core.handlers`) or

2/ write a script that parses your logs and send HTTP requests to your django instance.